# git mv with regex?

Tags: regex, linux, git, bash, for-loop

I wanted to move quite a few small app directories to one single directory called `snippet-apps`. I wanted to use `git mv` because I could then commit them as moved instead of deleted and created.

I couldn't figure out how to use regex so I did this:

```
for dir in *; do 
   if [[ $dir != snippet-apps ]]; 
      then git mv  $dir snippet-apps/ ; 
   fi; 
done
```

Now, I am no master at CLI and bash, but this or using `xargs` was a solution and it worked, but I was hoping for `git mv <regex>`.

Is there a way to use `git mv <regex>`? Or a simpler solution?

Comment: What is the error you have? What is the problem?

Comment: Git doesn't "do" regular expressions on path names, but this kind of `*` is not a regular expression in the first place: it's a *shell glob*. That said, using xargs or a simple shell loop is the way to go here anyway.

Comment: (If you wanted to get overly fancy: `git mv $(ls | grep -v snippet-apps) snippet-apps/` would also work.  This is because `git mv`, like regular `mv`, allows you to specify multiple paths to move into a single directory.)

Comment: @torek yeah, this seems to be much simpler then my overly complicated example. nice.

Comment: @MattClark no problem. Just looking for a simpler way, such as torek's example.

Answer (score 1):

what "git rm" provided is only [Pathname expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html), not regex.

You can write bash script to move files whatever you want under working directory, then run "git add --all" to collect all your modifications.

Comment: git add --all seems to only show 'deleted' and created directores instead of 'renamed' or moved. is there something special about --all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an extended glob (requires the `shopt -s extglob` option):

```
git mv !(snippet-apps)/ snippet-apps/
```

`!(pattern)` matches everything but `pattern`, and the appended slash makes sure we only match directories.